# Enumerate devices connected to my router using python 3 in Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, ping

I'm trying to write a script to check how many devices are connected to the internet. This is part of a bigger project to prove to my ISP that my internet sucks. I am performing a speed test every minute, and logging it to a text file.
I would like to log, at the same time, how many devices are connected, just to make sure that the problem isn't that the internet only sucks once a certain number of devices are connected.
There aren't multiple people streaming on this network, so I know that isn't the problem, but if it is a devices problem, that might be on me to upgrade my internet. 
I tried using the modules `neighbourhood` and `lanscan`, but I can't get them to work on my machine.

With `lanscan` I tried `lanscan.lanscan.networks()` and get the error message

> "module 'lanscan' has no attribute 'lanscan'"

My python IDE suggests that these modules should exist with this structure. `lanscan.networks()` give the same error except that it says "'networks' doesn't exist". Also, `neighbourhood` uses functions that don't work in windows, like `os.geteuid()`, so I don't think it is compatible with windows.

Is there a way I can find which of my devices are currently connected to my internet network? Actually, All I really need is the number of devices. I know that if I connect the IP address of my router/modem I can see the connected devices as names, and their IP addresses, so I should be able to find this information somehow, I feel.

[Neighborhood](https://github.com/bwaldvogel/neighbourhood/blob/master/neighbourhood.py)
[Lanscan](https://pypi.org/project/lanscan/)

Comment: from [`lanscan` source](https://github.com/sumpfgottheit/lanscan/blob/master/lanscan/lanscan.py) it looks like it should be used as a CLI or you can combine `main` & `networks` functions into your own function

Comment: Thanks for the tip Azat Ibrakov. Can you provide any inside on how to use it as a command line interface? I don't know how that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A second way is this, which is slower. This checks all ips from 0 to 255. I switched to an xfinity router, and found that they use pretty random numbers when assigning dynamic ips, unlike the motorola, which simply uses serial numbers starting from 192.168.0.10 (in my model). This answer is more general, then. I look at all 255 possibilities, but I limit the response time to 100ms (with teh paramter '-w' and '100', so it doesn't take forever. Should take about 25 seconds to ping everything, but if found it takes more like a minute.

```
for i in range(255):
    command=['ping', '-n', '1','-w','100', '10.0.0.'+str(i)]
    subprocess.call(command)

arpa = subprocess.check_output(("arp", "-a")).decode("ascii")
n_devices=len([x for x in arpa.split('\n') if '10.0.0.' in x and  
    all(y not in x for y in ['10.0.0.1 ','10.0.0.255']) ])
```

Answer (score 1):

I found one answer, though it doesn't appear to be 100% accurate. I notices that all the devices that connect to my router get straightforward names. My ip address is 192.168.0.1, so my devices are 192.168.0.1**0**, 192.168.0.1**1**, 192.168.0.1**2**, etc. Therefore I just ping the first 10 devices. I don't necessarily trust the response alone though. Once pinged I run `arpa -a` through the windows system with subprocess.

```
import subprocess

#this for loop depends on ho wlong you are willing to wait. I am
for i in range(10):   #look for up to 10 devices
    command=['ping', '-n', '1', '192.168.0.1'+str(i)]   #icrement the device names
    subprocess.call(command)   #ping the devices to update data before  "arp -a'

arpa = subprocess.check_output(("arp", "-a")).decode("ascii") #call 'arp -a' and get results

#I count lines that contain 192.1868, but not ['192.168.0.1 ','192.168.0.255'] 
#because those are the router and broadcast gateway. Note that the machine 
#you are running the code from will get counted because it will be in the 
#first line "Interface: 192.168.0.10 --- 0x4" in my case
n_devices=len([x for x in arpa.split('\n') if '192.168' in x and  all(y not in x for y in ['192.168.0.1 ','192.168.0.255']) ])
```